# Why my Windows NAT is inactive?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, nat

I run HyperV VM with Windows Server 2019 on my physical laptop with Windows 10. I want to have access to internet on Widnows 2019 so I created NAT on my Windows 10. I executed following command in PowerShell:

```
New-NetNAT -Name "HyperVNAT" -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.10.0/24
```

192.168.10.1 is a IP address of my virtual adapter (hyperV internal switch). Windows Server 2019's IP address is 192.168.10.101. It worked fine as long as I changed internet connection (preciously I was connected to network by Ethernet in my work, currently I am connected by WiFi to mobile network).  NAT is inactive now and I do not have access to internet from VM. I cannot remove NAT because I get exception.

```
Get-NetNat


Name                             : HyperVNAT
ExternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix :
InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix : 192.168.10.0/24
IcmpQueryTimeout                 : 30
TcpEstablishedConnectionTimeout  : 1800
TcpTransientConnectionTimeout    : 120
TcpFilteringBehavior             : AddressDependentFiltering
UdpFilteringBehavior             : AddressDependentFiltering
UdpIdleSessionTimeout            : 120
UdpInboundRefresh                : False
Store                            : Local
Active                           : False
```

As you can see Active is set to False.

```
  Remove-NetNat -name HyperVNAT

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation Delete on Target HyperVNAT PolicyStore Local
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
Remove-NetNat : The requested operation is not supported.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-NetNat -name HyperVNAT
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MSFT_NetNat (InstanceID = "HyperVNAT;0"):root/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetN
   at) [Remove-NetNat], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 50,Remove-NetNat
```

I am not sure if there is some command which can change my NAT status to Active, I tried following without success:

```
Set-NetNat -Name HyperVNAT
Set-NetNat : The request is not supported.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-NetNat -Name HyperVNAT
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MSFT_NetNat (InstanceID = "HyperVNAT;0"):root/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetN
   at) [Set-NetNat], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 50,Set-NetNat
```

I had the same problem few days ago but I used nested virtualization and problem occurred on VM. After searching in google and few failed attempts to fix it I gave up and created new  Viratual Machine from scratch. Now I have the same problem on my physical laptop and I do not want to reinstall operating system.
How to solve it?

Comment: This is not a PowerShell code issue. It's an environment configuration one. Step away from Powershell, do this in the GUI and you should see the same thing. W2K19 or not, PowerShell or not, this is standard network config stuff. A switch must be an internet-connected.bridged internet connection to allow egress access from any host configured. [hyper-v nat egress laptop](https://www.bing.com/search?q=hyper-v+nat+egress+laptop&form=ANNTH1&refig=58b3ad0417d7472d8c96199d9e4815ba&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=hyper-v+nat+egress+laptop&sc=0-25&qs=n&sk=&cvid=58b3ad0417d7472d8c96199d9e4815ba)

Comment: I should not have added PowerShell tag. I cannot find any useful information in link from previous comment. I have NAT network but this NAT network does not work and I cannot remove it. Before creating new Nat network I have to remove existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to clear some issues that can lock up ghost adapters and hard reset the devices:

- Open Hyper-V manager > Remove the virtual switch
- Delete all network adapters which are connected to VM or Hyper-V using Windows
  Device Manager > Network adapters
- Disable Hyper-V in Windows services
- Restart the pc
- Re-Enable Hyper-V and run `Remove-NetNat -name HyperVNAT` again.

Comment: I tried this solution when I had problem on VM. I also tried this solution with my current problem and both attempts failed. Maybe I do something wrong. What do you mean by "Disable Hyper-V in Windows services". I see 3 running services: Hyper-V Host Compute Service, Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management and HV Host Service. I just stop these three services. After PC restart these services are launched automatically so I cannot re-enable them.

Comment: I also disabled HyperV in Control panel->Programs and features->Turn Windows features on or off, restarted PC and re- enabled HyperV.